# Why python3 address is different between the 2 instructions in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python, pip, python3

```
~$ which python3.5 /usr/bin/python3.5

~$ pip3 --version pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (python 3.5)
```

one is `/usr/bin/python3` another is `/usr/bin/local/lib/python3.5`, why?

Answer (score 0):

One is the python executable (/usr/bin/python3 is a link to /usr/bin/python3.5) the other is just the directory where pip3 and the Ubuntu package manager install things, what makes you think it is a different executable?

Comment: Thank you very much ,I noticed that I confused  relationship between two different things.